# Convert a existing website to Fluid grid layout

Tags: css, responsive-design, fluid-layout

I have a website. Can I convert my website into a fluid grid layout? Are there any tools to automate this or do I have to create a fluid grid (in Dreamweaver) and insert `<div>` tags and insert my styles into it which will finally resemble my website.

Answer (score 1):

There is no tool that I know of which will create a fluid grid layout out of the box to a existing one. This is probably due to the fact that such a tool would have difficulty to decide which kind of grid structure should be used. Always remember that when using grids, the size of a column is fixed and therefore might not resemble the css that you have created using pixel-accurate css styles.

What I would recommend though is looking at the many frameworks out there. They are really easy to use and the only that you have to do is add class names to your div tags.

**List of Fluid Grid Frameworks**

- [Fluid 960](http://www.designinfluences.com/fluid960gs/)
- [CSSGrid](http://cssgrid.net/)
- [Bootstrap](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/index.html)
- [FluidBaseline](http://fluidbaselinegrid.com/)

There are like a million more of those. If you are just looking for a grid system that can be easily implemented without any hassle just use Fluid960.

**edit**
Lets say you had the following structure

```
<div style="width:100%">
 <div style="width:20%>First div</div>
 <div style="width:30%>Second div</div>
 <div style="width:50%>Third div</div>
</div>
```

In case of the 16 grid 960 framework you would need to take the 100% as all 16 columns. Therefore 20% (so your first div) will need to be a 3 grid column, your 30% a 5 grid column and your 50% a 8 grid column. Now you have 3 + 5 + 8 = 16 columns. In HTML you just end up writing

```
<div id="grid">
 <div class="grid_3"></div>
 <div class="grid_5"></div>
 <div class="grid_8"></div>
</div>
```

And you are done!

Comment: I saw in some video that i can use Adobe Indesign is it true or shall i start Dreamwevaer or something....

Comment: I've edited the original answer to give you a short introduction.